# Get the last active class on hover when mouse cursor leaves div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an accordion menu of 3 slides. I need to get the last active class on hover to be able to use it for a check condition to keep that slide open when the mouse cursor leaves the menu div. So far I was able to append classes to each slide but they only check if they're inside the menu div. Is there a way to check the only last active slide I hovered on?
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hopper86/pen/bYLGQB)

HTML code

```
 <div class="myMenu">
      <ul>
        <li class="mySlides slide1"><a class="img1" href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="mySlides slide2"><a class="img2" href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="mySlides slide3"><a class="img3" href="#"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
var slide1 = document.querySelector('.slide1');
var slide2 = document.querySelector('.slide2');
var slide3 = document.querySelector('.slide3');
  var img1 = document.querySelector('.img1');
  var img2 = document.querySelector('.img2');
  var img3 = document.querySelector('.img3');

/*  */
document.querySelector('.myMenu').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutMenu);
function mouseOutMenu() {
  if(slide1.classList.contains('insideMenu')) {
    slide1.style.width = '298px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_open_leszbs.jpg')";

    slide2.style.width = '21px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";
    slide3.style.width = '21px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
  } 

  if(slide2.classList.contains('insideMenu')) {
    slide2.style.width = '301px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_open_g8qfff.jpg')";

    slide1.style.width = '21px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
    slide3.style.width = '21px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
  } 

  if(slide3.classList.contains('insideMenu')) {
    slide3.style.width = '301px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_open_gcengd.jpg')";

    slide1.style.width = '21px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
    slide2.style.width = '21px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";
  }
}

/****************           1           *******************/
/**********************************************************/
document.querySelector('.slide1').addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver1);
function mouseOver1() {
  slide1.classList.add('insideMenu');  

  if(slide1.style.width == '298px') {
      slide1.style.width = '298px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_open_leszbs.jpg')";
  } else {
    slide1.style.width = '298px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_open_leszbs.jpg')";
  }

  slide2.style.width = '21px';
  img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";

  slide3.style.width = '21px';
  img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
}

document.querySelector('.slide1').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut1);
function mouseOut1() {

    if(slide1.style.width > '21px') {
      slide1.style.width = '21px';
      img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
    }
}

/****************           2           *******************/
/**********************************************************/
document.querySelector('.slide2').addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver2);
function mouseOver2() {
  slide2.classList.add('insideMenu');  
  if(slide2.style.width == '301px') {
      slide2.style.width = '301px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_open_g8qfff.jpg')";
  } else {
    slide2.style.width = '301px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_open_g8qfff.jpg')";
  }

  // close the rest of slides
  slide1.style.width = '21px';
  img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";

  slide3.style.width = '21px';
  img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
}

document.querySelector('.slide2').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut2);
function mouseOut2() {

    if(slide2.style.width > '21px') {
      slide2.style.width = '21px';
      img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";
    }
}

/****************           3           *******************/
/**********************************************************/
document.querySelector('.slide3').addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver3);
function mouseOver3() {
  slide3.classList.add('insideMenu');  
  if(slide3.style.width == '301px') {
      slide3.style.width = '301px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_open_gcengd.jpg')";
  } else {
    slide3.style.width = '301px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_open_gcengd.jpg')";
  }

  slide2.style.width = '21px';
  img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";

  slide1.style.width = '21px';
  img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
}

document.querySelector('.slide3').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut3);
function mouseOut3() {

    if(slide3.style.width > '21px') {
      slide3.style.width = '21px';
      img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
    }
}

/**********************************************************/
```

Comment: so you want to stop the slide loop when the mouse is on a slide or also when the mouse has hovered a slide and then comes out? but in this last option, the carousel will not slide automatically anymore...

Comment: Yes. Once the mouse hovers the menu div to stop the loop.
Is it possible to loop again, say 10 seconds after mouse cursor leaves the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a little modification to your code. I hope it fits your needs, by the way is a starting point:

```js
var slide1 = document.querySelector('.slide1');
var slide2 = document.querySelector('.slide2');
var slide3 = document.querySelector('.slide3');
var img1 = document.querySelector('.img1');
var img2 = document.querySelector('.img2');
var img3 = document.querySelector('.img3');


var timer;

/*  */
document.querySelector('.myMenu').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutMenu);

function mouseOutMenu() {
  if (slide1.classList.contains('insideMenu')) {
    slide1.style.width = '298px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_open_leszbs.jpg')";

    slide2.style.width = '21px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";
    slide3.style.width = '21px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
  }

  if (slide2.classList.contains('insideMenu')) {
    slide2.style.width = '301px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_open_g8qfff.jpg')";

    slide1.style.width = '21px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
    slide3.style.width = '21px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
  }

  if (slide3.classList.contains('insideMenu')) {
    slide3.style.width = '301px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_open_gcengd.jpg')";

    slide1.style.width = '21px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
    slide2.style.width = '21px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";
  }
}

/****************           1           *******************/
/**********************************************************/
document.querySelector('.slide1').addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver1);

function mouseOver1() {
  pauseTheLoop();
  slide1.classList.add('insideMenu');

  if (slide1.style.width == '298px') {
    slide1.style.width = '298px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_open_leszbs.jpg')";
  } else {
    slide1.style.width = '298px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_open_leszbs.jpg')";
  }

  slide2.style.width = '21px';
  img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";

  slide3.style.width = '21px';
  img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
}

document.querySelector('.slide1').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut1);

function mouseOut1() {

  if (slide1.style.width > '21px') {
    slide1.style.width = '21px';
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
  }
}

/****************           2           *******************/
/**********************************************************/
document.querySelector('.slide2').addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver2);

function mouseOver2() {
  pauseTheLoop();
  slide2.classList.add('insideMenu');
  if (slide2.style.width == '301px') {
    slide2.style.width = '301px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_open_g8qfff.jpg')";
  } else {
    slide2.style.width = '301px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_open_g8qfff.jpg')";
  }

  // close the rest of slides
  slide1.style.width = '21px';
  img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";

  slide3.style.width = '21px';
  img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
}

document.querySelector('.slide2').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut2);

function mouseOut2() {

  if (slide2.style.width > '21px') {
    slide2.style.width = '21px';
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";
  }
}

/****************           3           *******************/
/**********************************************************/
document.querySelector('.slide3').addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver3);

function mouseOver3() {
  pauseTheLoop();
  slide3.classList.add('insideMenu');
  if (slide3.style.width == '301px') {
    slide3.style.width = '301px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_open_gcengd.jpg')";
  } else {
    slide3.style.width = '301px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_open_gcengd.jpg')";
  }

  slide2.style.width = '21px';
  img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";

  slide1.style.width = '21px';
  img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
}

document.querySelector('.slide3').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut3);

function mouseOut3() {

  if (slide3.style.width > '21px') {
    slide3.style.width = '21px';
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
    /*img3.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';*/
  }
}

/**********************************************************/
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var index;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
  for (index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
    slides[index].style.width = '21px';
    if (slides[0].style.width == '21px') {
      img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_closed_pnlynb.jpg')";
      img1.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    }
    if (slides[1].style.width == '21px') {
      img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_closed_aonaaq.jpg')";
      img2.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    }
    if (slides[2].style.width == '21px') {
      img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_closed_tobbqu.jpg')";
      img3.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    }
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.width = '301px';
  if (slides[0].style.width == '301px') {
    slides[0].style.width = '298px'
    img1.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/1_open_leszbs.jpg')";
  }
  if (slides[1].style.width == '301px') {
    img2.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/2_open_g8qfff.jpg')";
  }
  if (slides[2].style.width == '301px') {
    img3.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511157235/3_open_gcengd.jpg')";
  }

  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    carousel();
  }, 2000);

}

function pauseTheLoop() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  console.log('stop loop');
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    carousel();
    console.log('restart loop');
  }, 10000);
}
```

```css
.myMenu {
 position: relative;
 width: 420px;
 height: 161px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 35px;
  outline:1px solid red;
}
.myMenu ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 display: block;
 }
.myMenu ul li {
 float: left;
 margin-right:5px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}
.myMenu ul li a {
 /*border-right: 1px solid #fff;*/
 cursor:pointer;
 display:block;
 /*overflow:hidden;*/
 height: 161px;
 margin-left:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myMenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="mySlides slide1">
      <a class="img1" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="mySlides slide2">
      <a class="img2" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="mySlides slide3">
      <a class="img3" href="#"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've added a control over the timer you create so you can destroy it when the mouse is over the slide and stop the loop for n seconds.
here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmYOrZ?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's definitely a starting point. Thinking of checking for a condition if the loop is stopped or not and going from there.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the way to keep displaying the latest active slide.
Created 3 variables:

```
   var lastSlide;
   var lastImg;
   var lastImgPath="";
```

Used them to store the image path for mouseover event
and img with slide classes for mouseout. 
This was repeated for all slides. 
Finally, added them to the main mouseout event at the menu's div which made this section way smaller:

```
document.querySelector('.myMenu').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutMenu);
function mouseOutMenu() {
  lastSlide.style.width = '301px';
  lastImg.style.backgroundImage = lastImgPath;
}
```

[Codepen attached here.](https://codepen.io/hopper86/pen/bYLGQB?editors=1111)